# Can Keen Intellect change Intuitive Attack?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, feats

Can a creature with both the feat Keen Intellect (*Oriental Adventures* 64) and the feat Intuitive Attack (*Book of Exalted Deeds* 44) use its Intelligence modifier instead of its Wisdom modifier or its Strength modifier when making attack rolls with an appropriate weapon?

Answer (score 9):

No, you can't. Keen Intellect says that you can use your Intelligence modifier instead of our Wisdom modifier when making Heal, Sense Motive, Spot, or Survival checks, and when making a Will saving throw. Therefore, you can use your Intelligence modifier instead of your Wisdom modifier when you are doing one of those things. Making an attack roll isn't one of those things, so you'll have to stick with your Wisdom modifier.